# Send Mongo results as response to Ajax

Tags: ajax, mongodb, express

I'm using AJAX to query MongoDB before a form is submitted. Once the first form field is submitted, an AJAX call is made to check whether a document with the same name already exists, and providing the user with the chance to view the existing document. Unfortunately, I cannot for the life of me find a way to send the successful MongoDB document that was found, from the server to AJAX

```
//SERVER CALL
app.get('/cocktail-check/:drinkname', (req, res) => {
    let seeker = req.params.drinkname;
    let drinkChecker = Cocktail.findOne({name: seeker}, function (err, foundMatch) {
        if(err) {
            console.log(err)
        } else {
            res.send(JSON.stringify({foundMatch: foundMatch}))}
        })
    })

//AJAX and JS
let exper = document.getElementById('ajaxSearchTrig').addEventListener('click', () => {
let drinkName = document.getElementById('cocktail-name').value
let trialText = document.getElementById('trial');

var httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();

httpRequest.onreadystatechange = alertContents 
    httpRequest.open('GET', '/cocktail-check/'+ drinkName);
    httpRequest.send();
    function alertContents() {
        if (httpRequest.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
            if (httpRequest.status === 200) {
                console.log({foundMatch})
            } else {
                alert('There was a problem with the request.');
            }
        }
    };

})
```

Answer (score 0):

findOne returns null when no record is found, so this may be the issue in your case.

First I would test the api with postman with this code, and  would be sure if api works as expected.

```
app.get('/cocktail-check/:drinkname', (req, res) => {

  let seeker = req.params.drinkname;

  Cocktail.findOne({ name: seeker }, function (err, foundMatch) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      return res.status(500).send();
    } else {

      console.log("foundMatch: ", foundMatch);
      if (foundMatch) {
        return res.json(foundMatch);
      } else {
        return res.status(404).json({ message: "not found" });
      }
    }
  })
})
```